# How to disable mouse acceleration on a Windows Precision Touchpad?

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-registry

As per title, is there some sort of registry tweak I can use to disable the forced mouse acceleration on a Windows 10 precision touchpad?

The usual enhance pointer precision option in mouse settings has no effect on precision touchpads.

Comment: What is a “Windows 10 precision touchpad?” Do you have a model number or something to help us out here?

Comment: @Appleoddity it is a generic touchpad driver built into windows 10 used on most modern windows laptops. In this case the touchpad itself is an Elan model (04F3/21D5) in an XPS 9550

Comment: There is no driver provided by Dell - it seems to be expected that the user uses the standard precision touchpad driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a registry entry that enables the existing 'enhance pointer precision' option to apply to precision touchpads:

In `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad` set `HonorMouseAccelSetting` (dword, should already exist) to `1`.

With this set to 1 and the standard mouse acceleration option off, I can confirm there is now no acceleration on the touchpad.