How to disable touchpad momentum in Windows 11?
I have an MSi Stealth GS66 12UGS laptop.
The touchpad has momentum (or inertia). It works like this:

When I drag my finger, then stop and immediately lift my finger, there is no momentum. (good!)
When I drag my finger, then stop (but do not lift my finger), the cursor keeps moving in the same direction until it eventually slows down (as if it has momentum). (bad!)

Here's a video showing the issue, where as I drag a window with the touchpad, you can see it slows down to a stop (that's not my finger, that's the momentum):
https://youtu.be/8FC2gmobtt4
I want to disable this super pesky irritating annoying momentum, but I cannot find any setting for it anywhere, and my Google searching and AI questioning has not yielded any results. Gemini and ChatGPT both give me answers that are correct (but for other settings), hopeful, or imaginary. Nothing works (if you don't believe it I'll post the conversations).
Various sources specify to disable the "Enhance pointer precision." option. I disabled the option, but that had no effect, and touchpad momentum has continued to persist.
I installed the "Intel Serial IO Driver" that you can find on that laptop's drivers page, in the "TouchPad" section, and that did not solve the issue.
Here's an image showing the three devices under "Mice and other pointing devices":

Here's an image showing the "Driver Provider" for all of them is "Microsoft" despite the fact that I installed the "Intel Serial IO Driver" driver and restarted the machine:

And here's a shot showing they're all "manufactured" by "Microsoft":

Is the official driver not being recognized?
In my Control Panel, there are are no specific settings for "touchpad", the "View devices and printers" only leads to Touchpad in the new Settings app which has no momentum option anywhere, and to the "old" mouse properties with nothing touchpad-specific:

All the sections in the Settings app for Touchpad, including "Advanced gestures" have nothing regarding momentum.
This Microsoft Precision touchpad tuning page lists registry entries that can be tweaked manually, including a couple that are not exposed in the Settings UI, but I do not see any that control momentum.  There is no mouse acceleration option in Mouse properties either.
How. on. Earth. do we turn off the touchpad momentum? Maybe someone knows a registry hack?
Is there any other information I can show that would help you determine how to do it? Please comment if so.

Have you tried this registry entry? https://superuser.com/a/1419518. It does not control momentum directly but rather forces the touchpad to honor the same settings as the mouse.

Your MSI laptop comes with SteelSeries GG app that allows mouse and keyboard customisations, with macros and more. Also check MSI Center app. If these apps are installed on your system, check if they have any touchpad settings related to 'momentum', or if any macros or other nonsense is interfering with your desktop experience.

The driver page you linked to doesnt even have a touchpad driver on it at all ! The intel driver is likely needed for how its is internall wired up, but doesnt function as a driver for your touchpad. Touchpads are typicaly made by Synaptics or ElanTech. The driver for your touchpad is currently the most basic microsoft driver, not allowing you to tweak much at all. If your laptop came with some driver tool from MSI to keep it updated, you may have to run that. Otherwise, call their support and ask where you can find the correct touchpad driver for your laptop, coz it aint on their support site

@Silbee Heh thanks, I contacted support and they were clueless about touchpad settings.

I would suggest going into BIOS and disabling Trackpad (if you can). Restart, then go in BIOS, and turn on Trackpad. Restart again, boot, to see if it works.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
